# Loading JQuery Mobile script is very slow

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I include `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js` as a script in my HTML file, but somehow the loading of this file takes up to 10 seconds in a browser!  I included a timer just before the script and after to measure this.

On a mobile device it takes 0.5 seconds , which is still quite slow, but acceptable.

Any ideas what is causing the delay in a desktop browser and how to avoid it?

Comment: Where are downloading the script? SIte or cdn? Have you got a test case?

Comment: I load it locally from my localhost apache server. Alle other scripts take 0-0.1 seconds but only JQuery Mobile is extremely slow to load.

Comment: How many other scripts are you loading, and what order are you loading them in? Also, are you loading the scripts in the head or body?